# WCF SOAP unencoded CDATA body

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, soap-client

I`m having a really hard time trying to figure out how can I instruct the WCF serializer to not encode the content of the SOAP body as it consists of a single XML node which MUST have a CDATA inner text, which in turn contains a valid XML. The problem is that the serializer encodes special characters, specifically < and > which breaks my request.

Is there any chance I could achieve this or am I to resort to old school string templates and build the payload myself?

**Edit:**

Here is a sample of the svcutil auto generated code based on the wsdl:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "urn:ANDR_service", ConfigurationName = "ANDR_servicePort")]
        public interface ANDR_servicePort
        {
            [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://soapAction", ReplyAction = "*")]
            [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
            WORKResponse WORK(WORKRequest request);
        }

  [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "WORK", WrapperNamespace = "http://soapEndpoint", IsWrapped = true)]
    public partial class WORKRequest
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "", Order = 0)]
        public string data;

        public WORKRequest()
        {
        }

        public WORKRequest(string data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
```

Notice the data string. I need to provide a CDATA string to it, but the output of the string is url encoded and the endpoint is rejecting the request (I don`t have control on the server, only the client).

1. I tried to use a IClientMessageInspector to manually revert < and &gr; to initial characters, but at the moment of inspection they are not encoded yet.
2. I tried changing string data to XElement data, but the serializer throws an exception.
3. I read about using the XmlSerializer instead of the default DataContractSerializer (link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-the-xmlserializer-class)) by decorating the contract and members with [XmlSerializerFormat] and use the XElement data. I got the same results as point 2.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. specifically a simplified model that demonstrates the problem.  You've clearly made some attempts that don't work; if you share them with us you're more likely to get an answer that does work.  See [ask].

Comment: But possibly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1375178) by Darrel Miller to [Using CDATA with WCF REST starter kits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1374062) might meet your needs?

Comment: You can try  converting the XML into a Base64 string and transmit that instead.

Comment: @dbc already tried that on point 2

Comment: @Jiayao I don`t have control over the server, only the client

Comment: I modified `WORKRequest`  to use `CDataWrapper` from [the answer I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1375178) by Darrel Miller, and the XML inside `data` was indeed wrapped in a CDATA section like so: `<data xmlns=""><![CDATA[<Invoice><Samples><Sample><AccountNumber>55761598808</AccountNumber></Sample></Samples></Invoice>]]></data>`.  Sample code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/C6bKf8.  Note the fiddle does not compile because dotnetfiddle does not support `System.ServiceModel` so you will have to copy & test the code yourself.

Comment: Does that answer your question?  If not, please share a full [mcve] showing your full code, the XML currently generated, and the XML you need to generate.  See [ask].